# Why is my code not able to update the database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble saving my entities after updating them. I can add new entities like this:  add(student); but if I tried this:

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
   db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
   db.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("someView");
}
```

I get this error message:

> System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateConcurrencyException was unhandled by user code
>   Message=Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or
>   deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager
>   entries.

Here’s my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ClassAttendance(InstructorIndexData viewModel, FormCollection frmcol)
{
     var instructorData = new InstructorIndexData();

     string[] AllFstMNames = frmcol["item.Student.FirstMidName"].Split(',');
     string[] AllLstNames = frmcol["item.Student.LastName"].Split(',');
     string[] AllAddresses = frmcol["item.Student.Address"].Split(',');
     string[] AllEnrollmentDates = frmcol["item.Student.EnrollmentDate"].Split(',');
     //more of the same code…

     var student = new Student();
     var enrollment = new Enrollment();

     for ( int i = 0; i < AllFstMNames.Count(); i++)
     {
         student.FirstMidName = AllFstMNames[i];
         student.LastName = AllLstNames[i];
         student.Address = AllAddresses[i];
         student.EnrollmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(AllEnrollmentDates[i]);

         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(frmcol["item.Grade"]))
         {
            enrollment.Grade = Convert.ToInt32(AllGrades[i]);
         }

         enrollment.StudentID = Convert.ToInt32(AllStudentIds[i]);
         enrollment.attendanceCode = Convert.ToInt32(AllAttendanceCodes[i]);
         enrollment.classDays = AllclassDays[i];
         enrollment.CourseID = Convert.ToInt32 (AllCourseIds[i]);
         //update rows
      }

      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
         db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
         db.SaveChanges();
         return RedirectToAction("someView");
      }
```

Can you help me with just being able to update values in the database?

Comment: Are there any changes? Or are sending an EntityState.Modified on an unchanged item? ie. does this happen on a AllFstMNames.Count() == 0?

Answer (score 2):

While I was looking at the code here, my initial thought is that it doesn't seem quite right to have a `for` loop that updates the `student` and `enrollment` objects multiple times and then to have only one call to `db.SaveChanges` outside the loop.  This is concerning because only the last iteration of the `for` loop will be applied when the data is saved to the database.  (You have a comment to "update rows" at the end of the `for` loop - perhaps some code is missing or misplaced?)

Then, I started thinking about why it would be necessary to manually set the `Entry(...).State` property.  Wouldn't the `db` automatically know that an object is modified and needs to be saved?  That lead me to this question:  Where is `db` defined?  What technology stack is being used there?

Finally, after making an assumption that the `db` object might work something like the MS LINQ-to-SQL feature, I noticed that the the `student` object is newly instantiated before the `for` loop.  This is fine for inserting new data, but if you are wanting to update existing data, I believe you need to first get a copy of the object from the database and then update the properties.  This allows the `db` object to monitor the changes (again, assuming that it has this capability).  (If this is not the case, then it leads me to wonder how the `db` will know which record in the database to update since you are not setting anything that appears to be a primary key, such as `StudentId`, on the `student` object in the loop.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I didn’t realize that my question was so vague.  I’ll redo the code starting with the first point that you made…updating multiple times but only saving the last update.  Thanks again.